# Which IDEs and text editors can deduce type of variables declared using auto keyword in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, ide, editor, auto

In ["Almost always auto"](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/) article Herb Sutter lists several reasons for declaring variables using auto keyword.

He says that actual variable type can be automatically deduced by IDE and shown by hovering over variable name.

I would like to know which IDEs and text editors (or plugins) currently support "auto" variable type deduction.

**Edit:**

**List of IDEs from answers:**

- Visual Studio 201x
- Eclipse
- Qt Creator 2.7.0
- KDevelop 4.5.1

**Text editors**

What about Vim, Emacs, Sublime Text, etc. - are there plugins which supports type deduction?

Comment: Eclipse supports this too

Comment: I would be glad to have this on emacs

Comment: I've submitted an issue to YCM inquiring about support for this, which would solve the problem for Vim: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/1404

Comment: Er, looks like it was just recently added as a feature: https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/pull/88

Answer (score 8):

Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2013 support type deduction for variables declared with the `auto` keyword. This applies both to the IntelliSense tooltips as well as auto-complete suggestions.

Starting with Visual Studio 2010 the C++ IntelliSense support was completely reworked (see [Rebuilding Intellisense](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx)). IntelliSense is now driven by the Edison Design Group (EDG) [C++ compiler frontend](http://www.edg.com/index.php?location=c_frontend). Whatever EDG can do you will see reflected in IntelliSense.

Note that IntelliSense tooltips will display the underlying type for `auto` variables. It will not work up the tree again and replace portions with appropriate typedefs. On Visual Studio 2012 the following code

```
std::string str;

std::string::iterator i1 = str.begin();
auto i2 = str.begin();
```

will display the iterators as

```
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::iterator i1
```

and

```
std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> >::_Val_types>::_Myt> i2
```

Given that I would happily disagree with Herb Sutter on his assessment that an IDE is enough to deduce a type when you need it. `auto` is great with respect to robustness, correctness and flexibility, but it surely fails to meet a developer's needs working on a large code base.

Answer (score 2):

### Native support

- Visual Studio 2010+

  - **Caveat**: Does not behave terribly well with typedefs; see iinspectable's answer
- KDevelop 4.5.1+

  - **Caveat**: Some incorrect deductions (e.g. float literals); see Johnny's answer
- Qt Creator 2.7.0+
- Eclipse (not sure if via plugin or native)

### Support via plugins

- Vim plugins:

  - YCM (since merging this pull request: https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/pull/88)
  - others? Syntastic, maybe?
- Emacs plugins:

  - ....SURELY there is such a plugin somewhere.

---

Note: the first draft of this answer was created by simply combining the existing answers plus the Eclipse comment, then adding a note about Vim. Without such an "aggregate" answer, this question (and its existing answers) appears to violate the "one right answer" rule.

This should really be formatted as a table; too bad we don't have that capability here.

Answer (score 1):

**KDevelop 4.5.1** also supports type deduction. Although it probably does small mistakes.

Examples:

```
auto i = 3;    // Deduces int
auto d = 3.0;  // Deduces double
auto f = 3.0f; // Deduces double - wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

**Qt Creator 2.7.0**  can do it too, judging from this testing source code:

```
class A
{
    void f();
};

int main()
{
    auto a = A();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small note: I checked Qt Creator and it knows the variable type and it offers auto-completion of methods/attributes, but when you hover over the variable name it doesn't give you the type of the variable (it does for variables declared without auto).

Comment: Another note, despite this is an old thread, Qt Creator does not support auto-completion for build in types (any std container will not provide auto-completion) nor for Qt types. Only for user defined types (tested with Qt Creator 3.2 RC1)