# Is it impossible to use IntelliSense and "auto" type inference at the same time on QtCreator IDE?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

I'm developing software on QtCreator IDE. And I love its IntelliSense functionality.
But the intellisense doesn't work when I use "auto" type inference, which is one of
the C++11 features. Is it impossible to use  IntelliSense  and "auto" type inference
at the same time on QtCreator IDE?

Here is my code.

```
QString qStr("this,is,test,message");
QStringList list0 = qStr.split(',');    // Intellisense for list0 works.
auto list1 = qStr.split(',');           // Intellisense for list1 doesn't work.
```

I expect the popup window for code assistant would appear when I type "list1."
Intellisense for list0 works (shown below).

[image: autocomplete dropdown screenshot from Qt Creator]

In .pro file, I added the following line.

```
CONFIG   += c++11
```

I use Qt Creator: 3.0.0 and  Qt 5.2.0 (MSVC 2012 32bit).

Comment: Just a side-question: why are you not using the final release as opposed to the beta? Also, what exactly does not work? You cannot autocomplete something about qStr.split(',');?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry for my ambiguous question. I edited the question in order to make the meaning clearly understandable. And I will try using the final release.

Comment: OK, I already gave a +1 because I think it is useful to talk about C++11 support, although your question is now even better visually. :-) In any case, why do you have mixed MSVC? "[Version] QtCreator: 2.8.82(3.0.0-beta) Qt: 5.2.0(MSVC 2010 32bit) C++Compiler: MSVC2012"

Comment: @LaszloPapp :I wrote wrong information about Qt Version. Please let me make corrections. I use Qt library built with MSVC2012. By the way, I installed latest version of Qt and QtCreator on my desktop PC. I didn't know the Qt 5.2 had been released officially until I read your comment. Auto-completion still doesn't work as I expected, However, thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried msvc2010, too? I would probably also try gcc/clang on Linux just in case.

Comment: Also, can you try this: auto qStr = QString("foo"); qString. -> does the autocompletion work at that point, i.e. without a templated class?

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I tried on Qt MSVC2010 version. and MSVC2010 compiler.It seems to be the same behavior about the auto-completion. As you said, I also tried this code.("auto qStr = QString("foo"); qString. ->") Then it works as I expected. I figure out the condition that auto-completion works. (case 1: TYPE object = someFunc(); object->[popup window will appear] , case 2: auto object = new SomeClass(); object->[popup window will appear])

Comment: I wonder if you could check this on Unix as well.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: Sorry for my late reply. I checked the subject matter on Ubuntu13.10.(QtCreator 2.8.1) It seems to be the same behavior of the auto-completion on Windows and Ubuntu. It might be independent on the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers to this question: [Which IDEs and text editors can deduce type of variables declared using auto keyword in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625115/which-ides-and-text-editors-can-deduce-type-of-variables-declared-using-auto-key)

It appears Qt Creator 2.7.0 has this feature.